# Serving Blazor WASM from Azure Blob Storage with caching

Tags: blazor, azure-blob-storage, blazor-webassembly

I typically serve all the files for SPA apps from Azure Blob Storage and enable caching so that they're fast to download onto user's browsers.

Is there any problem with doing the same with Blazor WASM?

To clarify further: I create a new Azure Blob Storage account for each SPA app I want to serve from Azure. I then place the all the files that make up the SPA app into `$web` container. Then I configure a custom domain and also activate a Verizon based caching service so that the SPA files are cached at all Verizon hops around the world -- at least after the first download.

This approach has worked nicely because the initial download of the app to user's browsers becomes much quicker.

I see no reason why this wouldn't work with Blazor WASM but wanted to see if anyone has experienced any issues with a similar approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this should be fine. Here are the responses I got to this question on Twitter: https://twitter.com/SamUresin/status/1513548165483569152?s=20&t=EEqVRO-DB2eG_AmXkRwyMg